Visual Studio use tabs instead of spaces for specific projects
Using Visual Studio 2022, although this should apply to all recent versions of Visual Studio.
We have a C/C++ DLL project written some time ago by another developer who used tabs instead of spaces. The team now uses spaces instead of tabs for new code:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs > Tab > Insert spaces (Tab/Indent size = 4)

We see three options for this project:

Convert the codebase to spaces only. Have a giant once-off "Cosmetic formatting code" Git checkin. Then use spaces only thereafter.
Do nothing. Just edit the code with new/edited lines having spaces. Most lines will have tabs, some will have spaces.
Since the code currently uses tabs, somehow configure Visual Studio to use tabs for this project only.

Option 1 is probably the simplest. You get a large "Not much to see here" Git checkin, but thereafter development is cleaner. Option 2 feels sloppy.
Before we go for the nuclear option 1, is it possible to ask Visual Studio to use one Tabs/Spaces setting for specific projects, but otherwise to use the main default?

You can set the format for the current project by creating an .editorconfig file in the root directory of the specific project. Depending on what you want to achieve, you can edit your .editorconfig file based on this MS document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/cpp-editorconfig-properties?view=vs-2022.
